# swift stop 360 degree animation

Tags: ios

in my swift 2 app, i have this extension:

```
extension UIView {

    func rotate360Degrees(duration: CFTimeInterval = 2.5, completionDelegate: AnyObject? = nil) {
        let rotateAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation")
        rotateAnimation.fromValue = 0.0
        rotateAnimation.toValue = CGFloat(M_PI * 2.0)
        rotateAnimation.duration = duration

        if let delegate: AnyObject = completionDelegate {
            rotateAnimation.delegate = delegate
        }
        self.layer.addAnimation(rotateAnimation, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

with this code, i can rotate an image 360 degree.
now i would like to stop this animation directly after i pressed on a button.

in my view controller is an action for my button. if i press this button, the following value will set:

```
self.shouldStopRotating = true
```

and i have this code part in the same vc, too:

```
override func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation, finished flag: Bool) {
  if self.shouldStopRotating == false {
     self.LoadingCircle.rotate360Degrees(completionDelegate: self)
  }
}
```

the image will stop after i pressed the button, but it will stop after the animation will be finished (after 360 degrees) - but this is to late.

the image have to stop rotating directly on the actual position after i press the button

Comment: Can't see where you did the stop in code. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1567855)

Comment: the only code part which i call after button press is this: self.shouldStopRotating = true, but i think this i not enough to stop the animation directly. now i am searching for the solution.

Comment: `removeAnimationForKey` in my linked answer should be the right call

Comment: i tried something like this before. self.LoadingCircle.layer.removeAllAnimations()
but the animation stops not directly

Comment: Super confused about your wording "Stops but not directly", or should it be "It will complete but not stop directly"?

Comment: it stops after the animation will complete

Comment: Try add a key for the animation, and see what happens after you cancel it explicitly. You may want to show the full content of your button click function.

Comment: this code is now in my button action. `self.LoadingCircle.layer.removeAnimationForKey("Test")`. and in the extension part i change this: `self.layer.addAnimation(rotateAnimation, forKey: "Test")`

Comment: no, still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this when the button that stops the animation is presse:

```
self.LoadingCircle.layer.removeAllAnimations()
let currentLayer = self.LoadingCircle.layer.presentationLayer();
let currentRotation = currentLayer?.valueForKeyPath("transform.rotation.z")?.floatValue;
let rotation = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(CGFloat(currentRotation!));
self.LoadingCircle.transform = rotation;
```