# CALayer path animation flickers when stopping and starting again

Tags: ios, swift, cabasicanimation

I'm trying to stop a `CABasicAnimation` and then start it again. To stop the animation at its current value, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1568132/14351818) answer which said to

> get the presentationLayer for the animating layer, read the current value of the animated property, set that value to the animating layer, and only then remove the animation.

However, when I start the animation again, I get a weird flicker effect, like this:

[image]

Here's my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let shapeView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 50, y: 50, width: 100, height: 100))
    var pathLayer: CAShapeLayer?
    
    let startButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    let stopButton = UIButton(type: .system)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        startButton.frame = CGRect(x: 50, y: 150, width: 80, height: 30)
        startButton.setTitle("Start", for: .normal)
        startButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
        view.addSubview(startButton)
        startButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(start(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        stopButton.frame = CGRect(x: 200, y: 150, width: 80, height: 30)
        stopButton.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
        stopButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
        view.addSubview(stopButton)
        stopButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stop(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        view.addSubview(shapeView)
        shapeView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
        
        let pathLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        pathLayer.path = getPentagonPath()
        shapeView.layer.mask = pathLayer
        self.pathLayer = pathLayer
        
    }
    
    @objc func start(_ sender: UIButton!) {
        guard let pathLayer = pathLayer else { return }
        let newPath = getConcavePentagonPath()
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: #keyPath(CAShapeLayer.path))
        animation.fromValue = pathLayer.path
        animation.toValue = newPath
        animation.duration = 3
        pathLayer.path = newPath
        pathLayer.add(animation, forKey: "path")
    }
    @objc func stop(_ sender: UIButton!) {
        guard let pathLayer = pathLayer else { return }
        if let currentValue = pathLayer.presentation()?.value(forKeyPath: #keyPath(CAShapeLayer.path)) { /// get the presentationLayer for the animating layer
            let currentPath = currentValue as! CGPath /// read the current value of the animated property
            pathLayer.path = currentPath /// set that value to the animating layer
            pathLayer.removeAllAnimations() /// remove the animation
        }
    }
    
    func getPentagonPath() -> CGPath {
        let pentagonPath = UIBezierPath()
        pentagonPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 0))
        pentagonPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 97.55, y: 34.55))
        pentagonPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 79.39, y: 90.45))
        pentagonPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 20.61, y: 90.45))
        pentagonPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 2.45, y: 34.55))
        pentagonPath.close()
        return pentagonPath.cgPath
    }
    func getConcavePentagonPath() -> CGPath {
        let pentagonPath = UIBezierPath()
        pentagonPath.move(to: CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50))
        pentagonPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 97.55, y: 34.55))
        pentagonPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 79.39, y: 90.45))
        pentagonPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 20.61, y: 90.45))
        pentagonPath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 2.45, y: 34.55))
        pentagonPath.close()
        return pentagonPath.cgPath
    }
}
```

Comment: Does that flicker happen on a real device? The simulator is not a reliable guide.

Comment: @matt actually, it does not! This is great! I was stuck wondering what I did wrong.

Comment: @matt Do you have any idea why this occurs on the simulator? I wanted to write snapshot tests for my animation but I also see these weird flickering animations when switching animations (set model layer to current presenation layer value and animations fromValue) :(

Answer (score 1):

While I'm not exactly sure why, setting `animation.fillMode = .both` or `.backwards` seems to solve the flicker problem. Per the documentation for this value:

```
The receiver clamps values before zero to zero when the animation is completed.
```

So I suspect what's happening is that when it is first attached, the animation is being shown at a time offset < 0 and by clamping it you ensure it shows a valid state at all times.